# Interpreting Georgia property tax digest record from 1850?

Tags: 1850s, taxation-records, georgia-usa

What does "g for Jane Burnett of color" mean other than her being a woman of color in the tax digest?
[image: Ga Property Tax Digest 1793-1892]

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thank you for having the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It is very useful to also include a link direct to the inline image but many of our users will not have a subscription that enables them to view it.  If you had included a picture cropped from that image that focuses on just the part you are asking about I think your question will be more likely to attract a potential answerer.  You can still do that using the [edit] and then Picture buttons.

Comment: The link to the database's own page, with the About the Database information (which anyone using an Ancestry database should read) is https://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=1729

Comment: Could you give more information from the Ancestry Record page to make it more clear which line of the image people should look at? I also agree with @PolyGeo that a cropped smaller image including the relevant entry would be more helpful than sending people offsite. A note about the location would also help, in case our community members know about research guides produced by local public libraries or societies.

Comment: @PolyGeo I can confirm that if you don't have a subscription, you can't see the linked image.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it means that Augustus Hinton was Agent of Rebecca Flinn (white) and Guardian for Jane Burnett a free person of color. Check the laws in effect at that time and place because people of color may have needed a court-appointed person to act on their behalf. In this case, paying taxes on Rebecca's land as her agent and (perhaps) a poll tax for Jane.